# How to select minified dependencies with gulp and 'main-bower-files'?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to create a simple gulp task that fetches all bower.json dependencies and inject them to my index.html file.

This is how my gulpfile.js looks like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('./public/index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles({
            paths: {
                bowerDirectory: './public/bower_components',
                bowerJson: './public/bower.json'
            }
        }), {read: false}), {name: 'bower'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

**And it works**. This is how my index.html looks like under ./build directory:

```
<!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="/public/bower_components/zepto/zepto.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

However, I'm unable to make main-bower-files to grab my minified dependencies (in this example, to include '/public/bower_components/zepto/zepto.min.js').

I have tried this override options:

```
{
    "overrides": {
        "BOWER-PACKAGE": {
            "main": "**/*.min.js"
        }
    }
}
```

and this:

```
{
    "overrides": {
        "BOWER-PACKAGE": {
            "main": {
                "development": "*.js",
                "production": "*.min.js",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it didn't work :(

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the package you want to override, `BOWER-PACKAGE` is here the text to replace. You don't want to override all of your dependencies and that's why it's one override by dependency.

So change your *bower.json* as:

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "zepto": {
      "main": "zepto.min.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see... my bad... :( Is there any way to set a 'global' option for all packages without specifying each package manually? I can create an inline function that receives the result array of bowerFiles(...) and replace *.js with *.min.js, however it feels like a bad workaround....

Comment: Using only `main-bower-files`, I don't think it's an available feature for now unfortunately

Answer (score 10):

There are two solutions.
First, you can use [bower-main](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-main) to distinguish minified from non-minified files.

Another option is to directly work on the list returned by main-bower-files and check the existence of minified files. This snippet replaces file paths by their minified equivalent when they exist.

```
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var exists = require('path-exists').sync;

var bowerWithMin = mainBowerFiles().map( function(path, index, arr) {
  var newPath = path.replace(/.([^.]+)$/g, '.min.$1');
  return exists( newPath ) ? newPath : path;
});
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vincent-zurczak/424c5d136063c120ee18) for a full Gulp task.

Comment: second option snippet is totally useful